# Airflow: Concurrency Depth first, rather than breadth first?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

In airflow, the default configuration seems to be to queue up tasks, in parallel, across days--from one day to the next.

However, if I spin this process up across, say, two years, then the airflow dag will churn through preliminary processes first, across all days, rather than taking, say, 4 days forward from start to finish concurrently.

How do I toggle airflow to execute tasks according to a depth first paradigm rather than a breadth first paradigm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have come across a similar situation. I used the following trick to achieve that **depth-first** behaviour.

- Assign all tasks of your DAG to a [single `pool`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L152) (with limited number of slots like, say, 20-30)
- Set [`weight_rule=upstream`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/23da4daaa018e72b39b977afcde85deaf2224f1e/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L505-L526) to all the above tasks

---

Explaination

- The UPSTREAM weight_rule reverses prioritization of tasks based on their *position across breadth of workflow*, resulting in all downstream tasks to have a higher priority than upstream tasks.
- This would ensure that whatever *branches* are launched will go onto completion before next branch is picked, thereby achieving that depth-first behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Try to toggle with the `parallelism` and `max_active_runs` parameters in your *airflow.cfg* and the `concurrency` parameter at your DAGs.